# C++ - Program returning 0 before finishing my function

Tags: c++, reference

EDIT: I've solved the reference issue, thanks for everyone's help, I'm now able to compile and run everything fine, but I can't figure out why the program is returning 0 before finishing the mainMenu() function now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int welcomeScreen(int &success) {

    string keyContinue;
    bool loop = true;

while(loop) {
    cout << "Welcome, traveler! Press 'Q' to continue to the main menu." << endl;
    cin >> keyContinue;

    if (keyContinue == "q") {
        success = 1;
        break;
    }
}

    return success;
}

void mainMenu() {

    int success;
    int menuSelection;

    bool loop;

    if (success) {
        cout << "MAIN MENU: \n" << endl;
        cout << "1. Login \n2. Register" << endl;
while(loop) {
        cin >> menuSelection;

        switch(menuSelection) {
            case 1 : cout << "login screen" << endl;
            break;
            case 2 : cout << "register screen" << endl;
            break;
            default : cout << "Please select an option from the menu..." << endl;
        }
}
    }
}

void exit() {

}

int main()
{
    int success;

    welcomeScreen(success);
    if (success) {
        mainMenu();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I enter 'Q' the program displays 'MAIN MENU' along with the 2 options, but returns 0 before I can choose an option and I can't figure out why. I'm new to learning C++ and this is probably a poor way to go about learning, but I thank everyone for the help.

Comment: Well, `success` wasn't declared in scope of any of these functions. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Pass `success` to a function. It's the generally accepted way of getting a variable into a function.

Comment: If your example doesn't even compile, it probably isn't a very good example. There are also deeper problems with your code... having those two functions recursively calling each other is asking for death by stack overflow, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `mainMenu (const int &passed)` or try to assign success first and pass it afterwards. You are not passing success , but the result of

```
sucess = 1
```

Also do you have an prototype for mainMenu ? Try to write

```
int mainMenu(const int& passed);
```

before `int welcomeScreen ()`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm currently researching what you suggested to learn more about prototyping, I'm sort of new to this. If you care to help further, I've finally passed the arguments fine and my program compiles, but I've run into another issue - if you check my edited post you'll see my full code and an explanation.

Comment: In mainMenu (). You need to give loop a value. `bool loop = true;`

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought bool values defaulted to true, everything works now thank you so much.

Comment: You should also give success in mainMenu () a value since it can lead to undefined behaviour if not. Although I dont think it is needed anyway